# MySQL storing player information

Tags: java, mysql

im getting started with learning MySQL and i want to practice using it on one of my java games, iv'e setup a database and am using Hikari as the pool,

How could i save multiple player items as a list? Ill explain how i store them in java in hopes you'll understand the question a bit better:

I have a Map for example you can have a sword category,and they type could have a diamond/gold or bronze coating as the items type, theyre unlockable so the Hashmap only contains the weapons they currently have. 
so a players map may look like this:
  Profile:
  map
     Swords: bronze, gold
     Bows: stage_one, stage_two

I want to learn the most efficient way of going about saving this information, is there a way to even just save a HashSet to the db instead atleast so i can get all the weapons into the db?

Not sure if a Set datatype is the same in mysql as it is in java, or whether i should just go with a giant string, and split it when i load it into java.. all seems a bit inefficient when it comes to checking hundreds of items (needing to load them all, split and check)

Sorry if this seems like one hell of a messy question, been working since 9am - 10pm on the core of this game.

Thanks for the help in advanced :)

Comment: better if you use Hibenate. Hibernate will manage it

Comment: In native mysql you can insert multiple rows with a single insert using the syntax, 
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES (x1,x2,x3), (y1,y2,y3), (z1,z2,z3);

On the other hand if you really need to persist objects to database records use something like hibernate to persist the database.
For more info please refer to the link bellow
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping